# C# - CS1503 - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#

Before you reply, I've checked my code over & over again and have also searched for about an hour now for a similar answer. The compiler keeps throwing the error CS1503, I'm not really sure how to fix this. It's on lines 36 and 37 and I've commented the lines that have the error, 36 and 37. It's for a database that is supposed to search for the license plate and output the other data in the table.

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=J:\Plate Reader\DB\InfoDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    SqlDataReader mdr;

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string selectQuery = "SELECT * From Plate WHERE Plate='" + txtPlate.Text;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlCon);

            mdr = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (mdr.Read())
            {
                labelName.Text = mdr.GetString("Name");  //Right here
                labelWanted.Text = mdr.GetInt32("Bounty").ToString(); //and here
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data For This Plate");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, mdr.GetString() and mdr.GetInt32 seem to require an int as parameter, but you're passing a string ("Name" and "Bounty")

Comment: Did you look at the docs for [GetString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring?view=netframework-4.7.2)? That method wants an int parameter not a string

Comment: Use `SELECT Name, Bounty FROM ...` to define the column positions explicitly and then you can write `mdr.GetString(0)` for the name and `mdr.GetInt32(1)` for the bounty.

Comment: @Ioror, the reason for your question being downvoted is that it seems like very little effort was made to check a solution (other than searching). Please read [ask] before the next question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in comments, GetString as well GetInt32 requires a parameter of type integer. That integer is the position of the field in the Select field list. If you do not want to use a position you could write

```
 labelName.Text = mdr.GetString(mdr.GetOrdinal("Name"));
```

and this simple line could be easily transformed in an extension method adding a method to a static class whose code is

```
public static class ReaderExtensions
{
     public static string GetString(this SqlDataReader source, string fieldName)
     {
         return source.GetString(source.GetOrdinal(fieldName));
     }
}
```

and this finally allows you to write

```
string labelText = mdr.GetString("Name");
```

of course the same could be written also for a GetInt32 that accepts a field name. By the way, if I am not mistaken the MySql version has these overloads directly in the assembly

Answer (score 1):

[GetInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32?view=netframework-4.7.2) is expecting an 'int' parameter.

You are passing in a string.

You need to [send in the ordinal position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal?view=netframework-4.7.2) of your columns.

use this instead:

```
mdr.GetInt32(mdr.GetOrdinal("Name"));
```

You might want to consider using a micro ORM like Dapper to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that [`GetString(i)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring) and [`GetInt32(i)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32) methods requires zero-based column ordinal as an parameter. If you want to retrieve data from the column by name you should use [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.item):

```
labelName.Text = mdr["Name"].ToString();  
labelWanted.Text = mdr["Bounty"].ToString();
```

Comment: I tried this but now it's asking for 'identification'
CS1001 Identifier expected

Comment: @loror I'm trying to reproduce your error and have no errors with this code